# MSBuild: Exclude secondary dependency

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild

I have a problem where an older version of a secondary dependency on one project is overwriting the newer primary dependency on another project.

```
Project A                   Project B
 |-> Dependency 1               |->Dependecy 2 v3.0
      |-> Dependency 2 v1.0
```

Project A uses Dependency 1 which uses Dependency 2 v1.0.  Project B directly uses Dependency 2 v3.0

Project A gets built later than Project B, and copies Dependency 2 v1.0 into the same output directory, which overwrites Dependency 2 v3.0 that Project B brought in.

How can I stop MSBuild from copying an older version of a DLL, regardless of who wants it?

Comment: I assume Projects A and B are in the same solution? If so, you'll just have bite the bullet and make then both dependent on the same version.

Comment: @simonatrcl not solution, but build script.  The hack-ey solution was to move Project A before Project B in the build order.  The parts of Dependency 1 that we were using work just fine with the newer Dependency 2.